# Array in array with PHP PDO fetch modes

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, pdo

Here is an extract of my PHP code:

A function that prints the query result from a PostgreSQL database:

```
function getOuvrage(){
    $conn = PostgreConnection::getInstance();
    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ouvrage WHERE code = '01'");
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();  
    print_r($result);
}
```

Result SQL query in pgAdminIII is:

```
  code   |forage  |  station  |  reserve
---------+--------+-----------+----------
 01      |      2 |        12 |       87
```

Result of `print_r()` function is:

```
Array([0] => Array ([forage] => 2 [0] => 2 [station] => 12 [1] => 12 [reserve] => 87 [2] => 87))
```

My questions: why are there 2 arrays and how can I get a simple array like this:

```
Array([forage] => 2 [station] => 12 [reserve] => 87)
```

---

**EDIT :**

I tried this:

```
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I still get the 2 arrays:

```
Array([0] => Array([forage] => 2 [station] => 12 [reserve] => 87))
```

I tried this:

```
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

I get this:

```
Array()
```

I couldn't find an answer to my question, including in the « duplicated » question pointed by @Your Common Sense!

Comment: You may find this reading useful, [the full list of PDO::FETCH constants](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes), just to make yourself aquianted with what to expect from PDO

Comment: Just edited my post. Still issues despite the doc you pointed to...

Comment: then you need fetch, not fetchall. the very purpose of fetchall is to return you array in array - so it's hard to expect a question like "why does  a kettle boil me a water?"

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
 $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```